# Bitmap.Save() method exception

Tags: c#, image-processing, video-capture

I am trying to write a windows application to convert `.avi` videos to bitmap frames. I am able to get the bitmaps but I am having problems saving them.

Frames are saved perfectly up to 1649th frame. After that I get this exception:

> *Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt*

I ran the code several times, the code always throw above exception when processing 1649th frame. The output folder is empty at the beginning and its size is 389 MBs when the program stops.

I am guessing that windows do not allow a program to write this amount of data in a short interval but I am not sure and I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help?

```
for(counter = reader.Start; counter<(reader.Start + reader.Length); counter++)
{
    DummyBitmap = reader.GetNextFrame();
    DummyBitmap.Save(folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath + "\\" + counter.ToString()      + ".bmp");
    reader.Position++;
}
```

Comment: Post code. how do we know what you're doing?

Comment: try to change the platform to x64 platform

Comment: Post code as Sriram said above.

Comment: If you are using a bmp object and not nulling it may cause that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitmap class implements IDisposable interface so it would be wise to use it as:

```
using (var b = new Bitmap(...))
{

}
```

Also, maybe this post can give you some answers: [Bitmap memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871610/bitmap-save-huge-memory-leak?rq=1).